# Trouble replacing dying vista with ubuntu

Tags: windows-vista

I want to replace my hardly working vista with ubuntu.

I downloaded the 32 bit ubuntu from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I got it as a comressed file. I decompressed it using winrar.

i then followed some steps that i cant seem to find right now,wich basically just said

burn it to a cd and restart, but vista keeps booting.

Comment: You downloaded an .iso, and do not need to uncompress it. Burn the .iso file directly to the disc. Using the "burn iso to disc" of whatever program you use.

Answer (score 2):

The file you downloaded was likely to be a ISO file. You need to burn this to a CD as an image (not data) and boot from that.

Then when your computer starts, enter the BIOS, find the area that talks about boot order, and make sure that your CD drive is higher in the order than your hard drive.

Comment: Or a create a bootable USB (instructions on Ubuntu's main site). I generally find it's easier/quicker.

Comment: Thanks Jan. yeah the instructions said to burn it, leave the cd in and just restart. however the cd doesnt boot just by itself. i "f2"ed my way to the setup menu, but i am not sure enough how to boot from the cd drive. feels like im gonna mess something up.

Comment: trengot thanks, ill try this if the cd boot fails

Comment: @thorbear79 to boot from the cd drive you need to change the boot order in your BIOS settings. Make the CD drive the first in the order of boot devices listed.

Comment: Also, i noticed when i extracted the files to a folder, they are only 4,39 mb large. seems small? plus, does it matter if i burn the folder i created for the extract, or do i need to open it and choose the files within?

Comment: @thorbear79 You don't do any of that. DO NOT extract or uncompress the iso. Just right click on the uncompressed .iso file and select "burn to disk" from the options given.

Comment: @mchid i see. that explains a lot. i will give it a go. many thanks.